# Using EJB transaction, when I insert a record in a main outer transaction, I can't find it in the inner transaction(Annotated by REQUIRES_NEW)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions, ejb, jta

My goal is inserting a record into my database, then updating it in a new transaction.

I try it like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="Table")
private EntityManager manager;

@EJB
private ITransactionTest itt;

public void insertRecord(int i) throws RuntimeException{
      Record record = new Record();
      record.setId(i+"");
      record.status(1);
      manager.persist(record);
      manager.flush();
      itt.updateRecord(i);
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateRecord(int i) throws RuntimeException{
      Record record = manager.find(Record.class, i+"");
      record.setStatus(2);
      manager.flush();
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I also try to use `getReference()` to retrieve my record, then it throws an exception saying entity not found. It seems that the entity no longer resides in the persistence context.

If I remove the annotation of `REQUIRES_NEW`, it works and I can update my record successfully.

So how can I update my record in a new transaction? How can I keep entities in managed status in the persistence context crossing transactions?

It seems executing a update sql query using JPA can achieve my goal. But are there any other methods?

Best Regards,

Kajelas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A persistence context is usually bound to a JTA transaction in Java EE, and a persistence context starts and ends at transaction boundaries (transaction-scoped) unless you use an extended entity manager."
 source : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/transactions.html.
JPA support only (theoretically) READ_COMMITTED isolation (see [Hibernate, spring, JPS & isolation - custom isolation not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234240/hibernatespringjpaisolation-does-not-work)) for an eventual workaround

Comment: Yeah, u're right. Perharps extended entity manager within stateful session bean is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_self_invoke_ejb 
I think that the problem is solved in that entry.