# org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I remix Spring Data and Hibernate in my Application to access MS-SQL Data.
In My All Service class,I set `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` in front of the class name.Recently,I observe some DB Table Locks occurrence.
Otherwise,I set`@Transactional(readOnly=true,isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)` to avoid DB Table lock,but it  throws

```
org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException: Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels - use a special JpaDialect for your JPA implementation.
```

How can I modify the XML to use isolation = `Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED` for dirty read?

```
<!-- JPA Configurations -->
<!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="myContactDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/GNWEB" lookup-on-startup="false" 
    proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/> -->


    <!-- use annotation in Service: @Transactional -->

<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     <qualifier value="transactionManager2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oracleConnection" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDB</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="oracleTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleConnection" />
     <qualifier value="oracleConnectionTransactionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"  />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="mssqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url">
        <value>${connection.url}</value> 
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${connection.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${connection.1qaz@WSX}</value>
    </property>    
</bean>

<bean id="auditInterceptor" class="com.bot.gnweb.unit.AuditIntercepter"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mssqlDataSource" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <value>com.bot.gnweb.model</value>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
       <list>
           <value>gnwebSql.xml</value>
       </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.bot.gnweb.model.MssqlCustomDialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>  
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="auditInterceptor">
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="gnWebPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mssqlDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
</bean>

<!-- Spring Data -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.bot.gnweb.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

<bean id="auditorBean" class="com.bot.gnweb.model.AuditingAware" />
<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorBean" />
```

Comment: You may to implement a custom isolation level support for the JPA.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234240/hibernate-spring-jps-isolation-custom-isolation-not-supported

Comment: Can You tell me the details about the XML setting which I lose?